# Datatable, using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable with 12 columns. 5 of them together makes primary key. I want to find the duplicate rows using linq and **assign value 'DUP' in a column of all those duplicate records**, (last column is kept for this purpose). please help..
Thank you.

Comment: And you didn't already tried something yourself? Something with DataTable and the Select method? Why do you say Linq in your title?

Comment: I have done the same by iterating through the datatable and all, but i need to do this using linq..

Comment: @sanuj: you have to show some effort. We are not a programming service. If you don't know anything about LINQ, read up on it, try something and, if it doesn't work, ask a question about why your code isn't working. We'll be happy to help then.

Comment: `but i need to do this using linq` Why?

Comment: sinde, somebody asks for help when he/she feels totally helpless. that doesn't mean that the person haven't tried anything. i have tried some linq codes but it didnt work. i m not able to post all those try-outs here. 

var duplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .GroupBy(r => new { rw =>  rw["colmn1"], rw =>  rw["colmn2"], rw =>  rw["colmn3"], rw => rw["colmn4"], rw =>  rw["colmn5"]})
                 .Where(gr => gr.Count() > 1)
                 .Select(g => g.Key);
something like this. 
showed error in group by part. 
i am nt able to recollect all the codes i've tried after that.

Comment: @sanuj: you have to put that in your question. We can't guess what you've already done.

Answer (score 1):

Here a complete example using Linq:

(I done the example using only 4 columns, adapting it to your case should be straightforward)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col1", typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col2", typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col3", typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col4", typeof(bool)));

var distinctRows = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   group r by new { col1=r["col1"], col2=r["col2"], col3=r["col3"]}
                   into g
                   select g.First();

foreach (var distinctRow in distinctRows)
{
   distinctRow["col4"] = "dup";
}
```

and if you like more the method-chain syntax:

```
var distinctRows = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => new {col1 = r["col1"], col2 = r["col2"], col3 = r["col3"]})
                                    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: I added the method-chain syntax for completeness

Answer (score -1):

How about getting the distinct rows according to primary keys then iterating through your DataTable to set DUP for the non distinct records?

To get distinct records try this

```
DataView view = new DataView(yourtable);
DataTable distinctTable = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);
```

Let me know if this solution is fine for you.

Comment: Thanks smiling4ever..

Comment: This does not use LINQ.